# Unir varios array en uno solo bidimensional en PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera unir varios array en uno solo bidimensional.

Cada array corresponde a los datos de una columna y quisiera saber si es posible juntar todos.

Mis array están en este formato:

```
<?php
$Id =array("1","2","3");
$Auto =array("BMW","NISSAN","FORD");
$Precio =array("1000","2000","3000");
```

El objetivo que quisiera saber si es posible, es juntar los tres array en uno solo, para que después pueda recorrerlos con un bucle `$listaAutos[i][j]`.

Trabajo con PHP 7.

Comment: Puedes revisar esta pregunta de SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301378/combine-arrays-to-form-multidimensional-array-in-php  parece ser lo que buscas

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué recorrería el elemento `[i]` y el `[j]`? Por ejemplo, ¿`$listaAutos[0][1]` valdría `2` o `BMW` en el ejemplo que has puesto?

Comment: Podrías colocar un resultado de tu ejemplo. Eso ayudaría a tener una respuesta mas específica. Con que objetivo? Ya que puedes almacenar todo en un objeto asociando el precio y nombre ($Auto) al id. Y sería solo dimensional (no bidimencional) y mas sencillo de iterar/buscar datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $Id =array("1","2","3");
    $Auto =array("BMW","NISSAN","FORD");
    $Precio =array("1000","2000","3000");



for ($i=0;$i<count($Id);$i++){
    $listaAutos[$Id[$i]][]=$Auto[$i];
    $listaAutos[$Id[$i]][]=$Precio[$i];
}

    print_r($listaAutos);
```

Esto dará como resultado un array así:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 1000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => NISSAN
            [1] => 2000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => FORD
            [1] => 3000
        )

)
```

Que puedes acceder mediante índices numéricos `$listaAutos[i][j];` del siguiente modo:

```
 for ($i=0;$i<count($listaAutos);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($listaAutos[$i]);$j++){
            echo $listaAutos[$i][$j]."<br>";
        }
    }
```