# Unir Varios Array PHP y mostrar el Tabla

Tags: php, array, html-tabla, tabla-dinámica

Tengo los siguientes Arrays:

```
$id_comp = Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 8 [2] => 8 [3] => 8 [4] => 8 [5] => 8 )
$tipo_comp = Array ( [0] => Egreso [1] => Egreso [2] => Egreso [3] => Egreso [4] => Egreso [5] => Egreso )
$fecha_comp = Array ( [0] => 2021-10-09 [1] => 2021-10-09 [2] => 2021-10-09 [3] => 2021-10-09 [4] => 2021-10-09 [5] => 2021-10-09 )
$concepto = Array ( [0] => Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Pinto Guerra [1] => Sueldo Agosto 2021 Jerson Carrillo Salas [2] => Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Obando Carcamo [3] => Sueldo Agosto 2021 Douglas Medel Perez [4] => Sueldo Agosto 2021 Cristian Leiva Argel [5] => Sueldo agosto 2021 Rodrigo Mora bello )
$debe = Array ( [0] => 1.672.432 [1] => 407.117 [2] => 1.244.522 [3] => 852.207 [4] => 1.513.820 [5] => 756.544 )
$haber = Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 )
$saldo = Array ( [0] => 1.672.432 [1] => 2.079.549 [2] => 3.324.071 [3] => 4.176.278 [4] => 5.690.098 [5] => 6.446.642 )
```

Necesito que se muestren en una tabla individual (por ítem):

```
N° || TIPO || FECHA || CONCEPTO || DEBE || HABER || SALDO
```

Este orden esta dado por el mismo orden de los array y su cantidad de elementos.
Probé lo siguiente (segun post https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/175012/47164) para unir y ordenar los array:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($id_comp);$i++){
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$id_comp[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$tipo_comp[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$fecha_comp[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$concepto[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$debex[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$haberx[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$saldo[$i];
}
```

Al imprimir efectivamente me muestra ordenadamente los array, pero al querer mostrarlos en una tabla, no imprime nada. Tengo esto:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <?php

  foreach($listaDatos as $fila => $i) { ?>
    <td width="60" style='line-height:'><?=$fila[$id_comp]?></td>
    <td width="86" style="text-align: left" ><?=$fila[$tipo_comp]?></td>
    <td width="86" style="text-align: left" ><?=$fila[$fecha_comp]?></td>
    <td width="286" style="text-align: left" ><?=$fila[$concepto]?></td>
    <td width="12" style='width:90px;'>$<?=number_format($fila[$debex], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
    <td width="10" style='width:79.8px;'>$<?=number_format($fila[$haberx], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
    <td width="10" style='width:79.8px;'>$<?=number_format($fila[$saldo], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
    <?php } ?>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Codigo Completo:

```
$ids_cuentas = Array(17,18,19,20); //ids de las cuentas que llegan por POST
$conexion->query("SET @saldo:=0");

foreach($ids_cuentas as $fila) {

   $consulta = "SELECT

   debe, haber,
   @saldo:=@saldo  + (debe - haber) AS saldo
   FROM detalle_comprobantes WHERE id = $fila";
   $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

   if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
  
     $saldo[] = number_format($row['saldo'], 0, ',', '.');//obtengo los saldos por separado

    }
   }

}

<table border="0" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td width="116" align="center" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">COMPROBANTE</td>
  <td width="276" align="center" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">TIPO</td>
  <td width="65" align="center" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">FECHA</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">CONCEPTO</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">DEBE</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">HABER</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7pt; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">SALDO</td>-->
 </tr>
 </table>


  
      <?php


      $consulta = "SELECT
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha, tc.id, dc.id) AS contador,
      dc.id,
      dc.id_comp,
      tc.nombre AS tipo_comprobante,
      cc.fecha,
      dc.concepto,
      dc.debe,
      dc.haber

      FROM detalle_comprobantes dc

      LEFT JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.id = dc.id_comp
      LEFT JOIN tipo_comprobantes tc ON tc.id = cc.tipo_comp

      WHERE cc.empresa = 2 AND dc.cuenta = 2104003 AND cc.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-10-30' order by cc.fecha, tc.id, dc.id ";

      $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

      if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
          $debex[] = number_format($row['debe'], 0, ',', '.');
          $haberx[] = number_format($row['haber'], 0, ',', '.');
          $id_comp[] = $row['id_comp'];
          $tipo_comp[] = $row['tipo_comprobante'];
          $fecha_comp[] = $row['fecha'];
          $concepto[] = $row['concepto'];
        }
       }

for ($i=0;$i<count($id_comp);$i++){
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$id_comp[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$tipo_comp[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$fecha_comp[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$concepto[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$debex[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$haberx[$i];
  $listaDatos[$id_comp[$i]][]=$saldo[$i];
}

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <?php

  foreach($listaDatos as $fila => $i) { ?>
   <td width="60" style='line-height:'><?=$fila[$id_comp]?></td>
   <td width="86" style="text-align: left" ><?=$fila[$tipo_comp]?></td>
   <td width="86" style="text-align: left" ><?=$fila[$fecha_comp]?></td>
   <td width="286" style="text-align: left" ><?=$fila[$concepto]?></td>
   <td width="12" style='width:90px;'>$<?=number_format($fila[$debex], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
   <td width="10" style='width:79.8px;'>$<?=number_format($fila[$haberx], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
   <td width="10" style='width:79.8px;'>$<?=number_format($fila[$saldo], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
  <?php } ?>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Alguna sugerencia?? Saludos y gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: @Excorpion gracias por responder. Los datos que puse en la pregunta, son datos reales, los arrays se crean en base a una consulta mysql. El orden en el cual fueron expuestos, son los mismo que en el codigo original. Aun así, necesitas la consulta o simplemente pegar todo el codigo? Saludos.

Comment: @Excorpion edite la publicacion y puse el codigo necesario para ejemplificar el problema. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Los datos que tienes en los diferentes arrays los obtienes de la base de datos? Si es así, ¿por qué creas una SOLA consulta que te traiga todos esos datos ya ordenados y luego lees esa ÚNICO array?

Comment: @A.Cedano me resulto imposible realizar lo que indicas. Obiamente generar la consulta no tiene mayor ciencia, pero el como se guardan los datos y el orden en como se obtienen los mismos, genera datos errones. Es por ello que opte por obtenerlos de manera independiente.

Comment: Entiendo, pero el hecho de que no hayas podido lograrlo no significa que debas optar por una solución que no es óptima, la cual a la larga podría traerte problemas. Las bases de datos son relacionales por algo, de hecho, una de sus principales ventajas es poder recoger resultados de varias tablas en una sola consulta, **no deberías renunciar a eso**. Si fuera tú, dirigiría mis esfuerzos a obtener un solo resultado, tampoco es tan complicado. Estarías sacando máximo provecho a los recursos y escribiendo un código más sencillo a nivel de PHP.

Comment: ciertamente el consejo de @A.Cedano es lo mejor, pero igual te dejo lo que podrías hacer

Comment: @A.Cedano completamente de acuerdo, pero debo cumplir tiempos por el trabajo y por ahora necesito hacer que funcione. Obviamente con mas tiempo y dedicación lograré el objetivo que me planteas. Muchas gracias por tu interés. saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano muy cierto; por eso yo suelo agregar 3 cosas en mi respuesta; la solución que espera el usuario; la solución que espera la comunidad y la forma mas optima ... aunque a veces los últimos 2 puntos convergen ...

Answer (score 1):

Según lo veo, y según entiendo, necesitas que tus arrays del principio, se combinen en uno solo que puedas manejar para pintarlos en una tabla específica. Veo que puedes hacerlo de 2 maneras:

### Usando [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Sabiendo que tienes diferentes arrays entre sí y necesitas unirlos, puedes usar array_combine de la siguiente manera:

1. Creas un array nuevo con los keys que necesites, en mi caso lo planteo así:

   ```
   $keys = ['id', 'tipo_compra', 'fecha_compra', 'concepto', 'debe', 'haber', 'saldo'];
   ```
2. Combinas tus arrays con las keys de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   $id_comp = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8];

   $tipo_comp = ['Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso'];

   $fecha_comp = ['2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09'];

   $concepto = ['Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Pinto Guerra', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Jerson Carrillo Salas', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Obando Carcamo', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Douglas Medel Perez', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Cristian Leiva Argel', 'Sueldo agosto 2021 Rodrigo Mora bello'];

   $debe = ['1.672.432', '407.117', '1.244.522', '852.207', '1.513.820', '756.544'];

   $haber = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

   $saldo = ['1.672.432', '2.079.549', '3.324.071', '4.176.278',  '5.690.098', '6.446.642'];

   $data = array_combine($keys, [ $id_comp, $tipo_comp, $fecha_comp, $concepto, $debe, $haber, $saldo ]);
   ```

Esto debería darte como resultado algo como esto:

```
   [
     "id" => [
       8,
       8,
       8,
       8,
       8,
     ],
     "tipo_compra" => [
       "Egreso",
       "Egreso",
       "Egreso",
       "Egreso",
       "Egreso",
       "Egreso",
     ],
     "fecha_compra" => [
       "2021-10-09",
       "2021-10-09",
       "2021-10-09",
       "2021-10-09",
       "2021-10-09",
       "2021-10-09",
     ],
     "concepto" => [
       "Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Pinto Guerra",
       "Sueldo Agosto 2021 Jerson Carrillo Salas",
       "Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Obando Carcamo",
       "Sueldo Agosto 2021 Douglas Medel Perez",
       "Sueldo Agosto 2021 Cristian Leiva Argel",
       "Sueldo agosto 2021 Rodrigo Mora bello",
     ],
     "debe" => [
       "1.672.432",
       "407.117",
       "1.244.522",
       "852.207",
       "1.513.820",
       "756.544",
     ],
     "haber" => [
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
     ],
     "saldo" => [
       "1.672.432",
       "2.079.549",
       "3.324.071",
       "4.176.278",
       "5.690.098",
       "6.446.642",
     ],
   ]
```

Teniendo un arreglo como el que te muestro, deberías poder hacer uso de foreach anidados para recorrer lo que necesitas y extraer la data:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."\n";
    echo "--------------\n";
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        echo $val."\n";
    }
    echo "--------------\n";
}
```

Teniendo un resultado como este:

```
id
--------------
8
8
8
8
8
--------------
tipo_compra
--------------
Egreso
Egreso
Egreso
Egreso
Egreso
Egreso
--------------
fecha_compra
--------------
2021-10-09
2021-10-09
2021-10-09
2021-10-09
2021-10-09
2021-10-09
--------------
concepto
--------------
Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Pinto Guerra
Sueldo Agosto 2021 Jerson Carrillo Salas
Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Obando Carcamo
Sueldo Agosto 2021 Douglas Medel Perez
Sueldo Agosto 2021 Cristian Leiva Argel
Sueldo agosto 2021 Rodrigo Mora bello
--------------
debe
--------------
1.672.432
407.117
1.244.522
852.207
1.513.820
756.544
--------------
haber
--------------
0
0
0
0
0
0
--------------
saldo
--------------
1.672.432
2.079.549
3.324.071
4.176.278
5.690.098
6.446.642
--------------
```

### Usando [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Para hacer uso del array_merge, debes modificar un poco tus arrays dados, y añadirles las *keys* que necesitas para identificarlos, así como lo pongo en el ejemplo:

```
$id_comp = ['id' => [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]];

$tipo_comp = ['tipo_compra' => ['Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso', 'Egreso']];

$fecha_comp = ['fecha_compra' => ['2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09', '2021-10-09']];

$concepto = ['concepto' => ['Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Pinto Guerra', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Jerson Carrillo Salas', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Juan Obando Carcamo', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Douglas Medel Perez', 'Sueldo Agosto 2021 Cristian Leiva Argel', 'Sueldo agosto 2021 Rodrigo Mora bello']];

$debe = ['debe' => ['1.672.432', '407.117', '1.244.522', '852.207', '1.513.820', '756.544']];

$haber = ['haber' => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

$saldo = ['saldo' => ['1.672.432', '2.079.549', '3.324.071', '4.176.278',  '5.690.098', '6.446.642']];
```

Luego haces uso del array_merge de la siguiente manera:

```
$data = array_merge($id_comp, $tipo_comp, $fecha_comp, $concepto, $debe, $haber, $saldo);
```

Y al hacer uso del foreach anidado del ejemplo anterior, obtendrías el mismo resultado

Te dejo [el link de pruebas](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e7dd2832b49dc37109e54c6de6027155a9e5281)